# Reference a column in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have created a table where I am trying to reference a column in another table

I have created this table

```
create table Courses (
    course_id serial primary key,
    coursename varchar(50) not null,
    teacher varchar (50)
)
```

And now trying to create another table, with a foreign key to the table above, on the column `course_id`, like this

```
create table Student
(
    student_id serial primary key,
    firstname varchar (50) not null, 
    lastname varchar (50) not null,
    email varchar (50) not null,
    courses text[], 
    constraint fk_course
        foreign key(course_id)
            references Courses(course_id)           
)
```

I am getting the error:

```
ERROR:  column "course_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist 

SQL state: 42703
```

But the column does exist, so I don't know why it says that. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The issue:  There is no`course_id` in `student` which is causing the error. As to table naming see [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Short version un-double quoted table name will be folded to lower case. Lastly spend some time here [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) in the *REFERENCES reftable [ ( refcolumn ) ]  ... section*.

Comment: course_id doesn't exist in the table student. Besides that, you want a table between these two, the associative table. Don't use an array, that will cause many challenges. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: Thanks guys, I see what you mean. I'm new to this, trying to learn. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a new table for many to many relationship

```sql
CREATE TABLE course (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ,name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,teacher VARCHAR (50)
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE student (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
    ,firstname VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
    ,lastname VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
    ,email VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL
);
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE student_and_course (
    student INT
    ,course INT
    ,PRIMARY KEY (student,course)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (student)
        REFERENCES student (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ,FOREIGN KEY (course)
        REFERENCES course (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

You can go even further with `teacher` being another relationship